# mvc3, getting name and values from dropdowns in Razor Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to get the "Name" and "Value" from a dropdownlist box from a MVC3 Razor View. What is the best approach please?

Razor Code:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Occupation.PK, Model.GetLUV("Occupation",Model.Occupation.PK))
         </div>
```

Resultant HTML:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
             <label for="Occupation">Occupation</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <select id="Occupation_PK" name="Occupation.PK"><option value="17">IT</option>
              <option value="18">Accountant</option>
              <option selected="selected" value="19">Solicitor</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Occupation" data-valmsg- replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

IE I want to store PK=17 and Occupation="IT", not just PK=17. I am persisting it to XML.

My initial thoughts are to add a hidden field and then use some form of javascript to populate it at runtime. I believe I need the extra field to ensure modelbiding can pick it up to populate the XML.

Many thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a drop-down would be editable by a malicious user on their browser, allowing them to store whatever Occupation value they pleased in your database.  This would not be desirable.

You probably want to do a lookup on the server side, when the form is posted back.  The lookup service would take an id (17 in this case) and return you a string ('IT').  Then the user cannot play around maliciously with the value.

Comment: The user always can save the HTML, modify it and use it to send altered value back to the server. Or they don't even need to save it, they can just use firebug or other tools like that.
Anyway the server-side lookup is a possible solution.

Comment: Exactly.  That's why I'm recommending a lookup on the server side on the post back.